# Using TDS can I make a single update package?

Tags: tds, update-packages

In the Helix context (foundation/feature/project) I have multiple TDS projects. I can configure them to create an update package.

But can I configure TDS through the  TdsGlobal.config to create a single update package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The way I have it setup, I use a Project layer TDS project to bundle all the other TDS projects up.

If you go into the properties of the TDS Project and load the **Multi-Project Properties** tab. You can then set the **Package Bundling** properties. So in your main TDS project that you want to create the update package, add in all the other projects:

[image]

This is not something you would set in the `TDSGlobal.config` as it only needs to apply to a single project. Trying to add this to the global config would mean that all TDS projects had dependencies on each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use package bundling to create a single package containing items from multiple other TDS projects, see screenshot below. 
I have never tried putting this in the TdsGlobal.config but this should probably work just like any other project setting.
[image]